# Receipt tracking with purchase breakdown

Tags: finance, scanning

I'm looking for an iOS app or a web app that will let me scan a receipt and breakdown the purchases on the receipt so I can put each purchase into a category.

I run my own small nonprofit and frequently buy personal things and business things when I go to the store, so they're mixed on the receipt.

So far I can only find software that will show the total of the receipt but not break it down. Doing that all by hand is a pain. Any ideas?